# How does one go about making a triple shot effect that rotates in accordance to where the player is aiming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I am working on a top-down shooter game project. I have been having problems creating a triple shot effect where the player would shoot 3 bullets. These bullets would be parallel to each other at the same angle as where the player would aim.

[image: Example of what i am trying to do.]

*The above example shows two fire angles from the player where one goes to the left and one goes up.*

The current problem is that i have little to no idea how i would attempt to do this as i am quite bad at math. My first attempt went very poorly as seen below.

https://gyazo.com/c5be55ce07f7e81ad1786cd91ecc37ad

I have researched this in my previous math books and i have come to the conclusion that i need to be focusing on trigonometry (specifically sin and cos). I just dont know how exactly i am going to implement the logic for the triple shot effect.

Here is the code for the first attempt:

```
public class TripleShot : CoreWeaponPart
    {
        public enum FireType { Spread, Row }
        public FireType fireType;
        public override Bullet[] FirePattern(PlayerController owner, Weapon mainWeapon)
        {
            Bullet[] bullets = new Bullet[3 + mainWeapon.fireAmount];
            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
            {
                Bullet bullet = ObjectPooler.GetPooledObject<Bullet>(true); //Get an available bullet from the pool of bullets.
                bullet.Damage = mainWeapon.damage;
                bullet.Lifespan = mainWeapon.bulletLifespan;
                bullet.Owner = owner;

                switch (fireType)
                {
                    case FireType.Spread: //Create a spread effect for the tripleshot.
                        bullet.transform.position = owner.barrelPos.position;
                        bullet.transform.rotation = (owner.barrelPos.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, -29.5f, 0)) * Quaternion.Euler(0, 15f * (i + 1f + mainWeapon.fireSpread), 0);
                        break;

                    case FireType.Row: //Create a parallel effect for the tripleshot (current problem).

                        bullet.transform.position = owner.barrelPos.position - (transform.forward + new Vector3(5 + mainWeapon.fireSpread, 0, 0)) + (new Vector3(5 * (i + 1f + mainWeapon.fireSpread), 0, 0));
                        bullet.transform.rotation = owner.barrelPos.rotation;
                        break;

                }


                bullet.Direction = bullet.transform.forward.normalized * mainWeapon.bulletVelocity;

                bullet.SetActive(true);

                bullets[i] = bullet;
            }

            return bullets;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to draw a right triangle where the 3 sides are 1) The wall 2) A line from the shooter to the wall 3) The line the bullet is traveling.  You get the angle that the bullet hits the wall which is 90 - Angle bullet is fired.  When the bullet hits the wall it will bounce off wall at same angle that it hits the wall.  So if bullet hits wall at 30 degrees is will bounce off of wall at 30 degree in opposite direction (180 - 30 = 150).

Comment: Cool idea, but that is not really what i am looking for. I am trying to figure out how to shoot 3 bullets in parallel and in a correct rotation based on player aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use trigonometry for this. Instead, use transforms to do the work for you.

First, add a `maxParallelSpread` term so you can prevent bullets from being fired from an absurd distance away when very many bullets are being fired.

Then, you can define `parallelSpread`, the distance for the bullets to go to the left or the right of the barrel to be `Mathf.Min(maxParallelSpread, (bullets.Length-1) * mainWeapon.fireSpread)`. Then each bullet is positioned at this portion along that distance: `(float)i/(bullets.Length-1)`

You can use `Mathf.Lerp(-parallelSpread, parallelSpread, (float)i/(bullets.Length-1))` to calculate how far to move the bullet along `transform.right` from the barrel's position.

Altogether:

```
public class TripleShot : CoreWeaponPart
{
    public enum FireType { Spread, Row }
    public FireType fireType;
    public maxParallelSpread = 5f;

    public override Bullet[] FirePattern(PlayerController owner, Weapon mainWeapon)
    {
        Bullet[] bullets = new Bullet[3 + mainWeapon.fireAmount];
        float parallelSpread = Mathf.Min(maxParallelWidth, (bullets.Length-1) 
                * mainWeapon.fireSpread);
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Length; i++)
        {
            //Get an available bullet from the pool of bullets.
            Bullet bullet = ObjectPooler.GetPooledObject<Bullet>(true); 

            bullet.Damage = mainWeapon.damage;
            bullet.Lifespan = mainWeapon.bulletLifespan;
            bullet.Owner = owner;

            switch (fireType)
            {
                case FireType.Spread: //Create a spread effect for the tripleshot.
                    bullet.transform.position = owner.barrelPos.position;
                    bullet.transform.rotation = ( owner.barrelPos.rotation 
                            * Quaternion.Euler(0, -29.5f, 0)) 
                            * Quaternion.Euler(0, 15f * (i + 1f 
                            + mainWeapon.fireSpread), 0);
                    break;

                case FireType.Row: //Create a parallel effect for the tripleshot
                    float bulletRightness = Mathf.Lerp(-parallelSpread, 
                            parallelSpread, (float)i/(bullets.Length-1));
                    bullet.transform.position = owner.barrelPos.position 
                            + transform.right * bulletRightness;
                    bullet.transform.rotation = owner.barrelPos.rotation;
                    break;

            }


            bullet.Direction = bullet.transform.forward.normalized 
                    * mainWeapon.bulletVelocity;

            bullet.SetActive(true);

            bullets[i] = bullet;
        }

        return bullets;
    }
}
```

And you can adjust how much spreading `mainWeapon.fireSpread` results in `parallelSpread` by multiplying a constant that suits your needs. for instance, if you need it to spread twice as much, multiply it by 2f:

```
        float parallelSpread = Mathf.Min(maxParallelWidth, (bullets.Length-1) 
                * 2f * mainWeapon.fireSpread);
```